# How to mask email addresses in logs of RoR application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to mask all email addresses in logs of RoR application.

`user@example.test` -> `***`

Answer (score 0):

In you application.rb file use

filter_parameter_logging “email”

Comment: It's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `filter_parameter_logging` file in `initializers` then create one and set following

```
Rails.application.config.filter_parameters += [
  :email, :password, :anything_else
]
```